# Laravel 5 Multiple 301 redirects on old urls

Tags: redirect, routes, laravel-5

I have a array of old indexed url's

```
$redirects = array(
    '/en/sitemap.php' => 'http://www.example.com/sitemap',
    '/en/contact.php' => 'http://www.example.com/sitemap',
    '/en/analysis.php?id=1' => 'http://www.example.com/sitemap',
    ... etc
    '/de/sitemap.php' => 'http://www.example.de/sitemap',
    '/de/contact.php' => 'http://www.example.de/contact',
    '/de/analysis.php?id=1' => 'http://www.example.de/analysis/productname',
    ... etc
)
```

And I want to redirect these in the routes.php file:

```
foreach($redirects as $old => $new){
    Route::get($old, function() use($new) {
        return Redirect::to($new, 301);
    });
}
```

Most of it is working but Laravel does not seem to pick up the query urls (?id=1 is stripped). I do not want to use htaccess or apache http.conf.

How do I get the full query url's in this example to work?

Comment: Better to create a middleware to handle this. Routes don't take query strings.

Comment: There is a solution [how to redirect  old url to new url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306596/how-to-redirect-old-url-to-new-url-laravel-htacces)